# Sql server 2008 R2 ошибка при создании триггера

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEL_REYS ON DATABASE FOR <data_definition_statements, , 
DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE> AS IF IS_MEMBER ('db_owner') = 0 
BEGIN PRINT 'You must ask your DBA to drop or alter tables!' ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
END 
GO
```

> Сообщение 102, уровень 15, состояние 1, процедура DEL_REYS, строка 3
>   Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "<". ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
>   Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "<".

Comment: в данном случае достаточно просто посмотреть примеры создания триггеров и понять, что следует просто подкорректировать 
 автосгенерированный код и всё взлетит, не понятно за что плюсовали этот вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEL_REYS
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE
AS
  IF IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 0
    PRINT 'You must ask your DBA to drop or alter tables!'
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!